# How to override particular function of javascript in Magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript

I need to override the particular function (for example : **accountFieldsBind**) of `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/web/order/create/scripts.js`

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: Follow this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272577/how-to-extend-admin-js-in-magento-2-by-mixins

Answer (score 8):

Add the following to your Require JS config:

```
var config = {
 config: {
     mixins: {
         'Module_Name/js/path/to/js/file': {
             'Your_Theme/js/path/to/new/js/file': true
         }
     }
 }
};
```

And inside `Your_Theme/js/path/to/new/js/file.js` you need to return the function(s) you need to extend. How you do this depends on how the file was written, for example if it's using object literal JS or it's just a singular function.

In my example below I'm extending/overriding a function from a UI component, `this._super();` is important to note as this will runthe original function. So if you need to extend the function and do additional logic you can use this, if you want to fully overwrite the function you can leave it out.

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({

            functionYouAreOverriding: function () {
               this._super(); // This will run the original function, you may or may not need this.

                //... Your new code
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I'm not sure on the exact syntax you need to use as the file you mention uses `AdminOrder.prototype`, my guess would be:

```
return AdminOrder.prototype = {
    functionToOverride: function() {
        ...
    }
}
```

For more info see the official dev docs - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html

Comment: Thanks Ben, Yes I tried this but its not working

Comment: @AmitNaraniwal did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new module and add a **reqired-config.js** in

> MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts": "MyVendor_MyModule/js/order/create/scripts",
        }
    }
}
```

And create

> MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/web/js/order/create/scripts.js

In you module and this can override the file

Comment: This overrides the entire file. OP's question was asking how to override a specific function.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts': {
                'MyVendor_myModule/js/order/create/scriptUpdate': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**OR**

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts": "MyVendor_myModule/js/order/create/scripts",
        }
    }
}
```

In that case your overwrite js location

```
MyVendor/myModule/view/adminhtml/web/js/order/create/scripts.js
```

Comment: Have you an idea about how to override `_calcProductPrice` function in custom `scripts.js` file (using mixins)?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below URL
[How to extend admin js in magento 2 by mixins](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272577/how-to-extend-admin-js-in-magento-2-by-mixins)

It will solve the problem.

```
/* global AdminOrder */
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts'
], function (jQuery) {
    'use strict';

    AdminOrder.prototype.loadShippingRates = function () {
        var addressContainer = this.shippingAsBilling ?
            'billingAddressContainer' :
            'shippingAddressContainer',
            data = this.serializeData(this[addressContainer]).toObject();

        data['shipto_type'] = document.querySelector("#shipto_type").value;
        data['liftgate'] = document.querySelector("#liftgate").value;

        data['collect_shipping_rates'] = 1;
        this.isShippingMethodReseted = false;
        this.loadArea(['shipping_method', 'totals'], true, data);

        return false;
    }
});
```