# How to extend admin js in magento 2 by mixins

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, prototype-js, mixins

I want to overide

```
Magento_Sales/adminhtml/web/order/create/scripts.js
```

### I wrote require-config.js for this

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Sales/adminhtml/web/order/create/scripts.js': {
                'Magento_Sales/web/order/create/scripts-mixins.js': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

My implementation is in file

```
Magento_Sales/web/order/create/scripts-mixins.js
define([
    "jquery",
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    "mage/translate",
    "prototype",
    "Magento_Catalog/catalog/product/composite/configure",
    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/async'
], function(jQuery, confirm, alert){

   return AdminOrder.prototype = {
       setCustomerId : function(id){
            return false;
            this.customerId = id;
            this.loadArea('header', true);
            $(this.getAreaId('header')).callback = 'setCustomerAfter';
            $('back_order_top_button').hide();
            $('reset_order_top_button').show();
        }
   }
});
```

But its not working.
its always executing parent class function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not use js mixin for the particular js file you try to override (i.e */vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/web/order/create/scripts.js*). Also, your  **require-config.js** declaration is wrong but this not matter since mixin will not work for the js file */vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/web/order/create/scripts.js*

You may try below steps to override this AdminOrder class of the scripts.js file

I assume you are using a custom Module "**Company_MyModule**"

**Step 1)**

Create a xml file **sales_order_create_index.xml** under  **/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/adminhtml/layout**

File : ***/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">        
    <referenceContainer name="js">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Company_MyModule::order/create/js.phtml" name="create2"/>
     </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

**step 2)**

Create a phtml file **js.phtml** under  ***/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create***

File : **/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/js.phtml**

```
<script>
require([
    "prototype",
    "Company_MyModule/js/order/create/scripts"
], function(){



});
</script>
```

**step 3)**

Create js file **scripts.js** under  ***/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/adminhtml/web/js/order/create*** to override AdminOrder class.

File: ***/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/adminhtml/web/js/order/create/scripts.js***

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/* global AdminOrder */
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts'
], function (jQuery) {
    'use strict';


    AdminOrder.prototype.setCustomerId = function(id){
           //console.log("override setCustomerId called");
        return false;
            this.customerId = id;
            this.loadArea('header', true);
            $(this.getAreaId('header')).callback = 'setCustomerAfter';
            $('back_order_top_button').hide();
            $('reset_order_top_button').show();

        }
});
```

**step 4)**

Clear your Magento Cache and alson remove adminhtml static files also.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/*
```

Answer (score 4):

I am curious to know why would Magento won't allow using mixins on such file... any quick explanation about it?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is another way to extend a class method that worked for me. Example:

**scripts-mixins.js**

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';

    if (typeof AdminOrder !== "undefined") {
        (function(setCustomerId) {
            AdminOrder.prototype.setCustomerId = function() {
                // console.log('replaced');
                var result = setCustomerId.apply(this, arguments);

                // custom logic here

                return result;
            };
        })(AdminOrder.prototype.setCustomerId);
    }

    // another implementation... (works the same)

    // var setCustomerId = AdminOrder.prototype.setCustomerId;
    // AdminOrder.prototype.setCustomerId = function() {
    //     // console.log('replaced');
    //     var result = setCustomerId.apply(this, arguments);
    //
    //     // custom logic here
    //
    //     return result;
    // };
});
```

Inspired: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10057969/12298367

Comment: for me, `AdminOrder` is always undefined, thus I need to access it with `window.` prefix