# How we can use Js Mixins for order scripts.js

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, requirejs, mixins

I want to override `switchPaymentMethod` from `module-sales/view/adminhtml/web/order/create/scripts.js` for that I use mixins:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts': {
                'Vendor_Module/order/create/scripts-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/order/create/scripts-mixin.js

```
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        switchPaymentMethod: function(method){
            console.log('funcion called');
            //Main Code
        },
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

**I got this error in console: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined**

I also tried with override AdminOrder.prototype = { }

Any help would be appreciated...!

Comment: @Patel Did you solve this?

Comment: @ManoM Yes, After deep into the code found that you can't use mixins in this case. I will provide my solution soon here.

Comment: Okay, @Patel. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: You can use this solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272577/how-to-extend-admin-js-in-magento-2-by-mixins

Answer (score 0):

you must  change config to :

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Vendor_Module/order/create/scripts-mixin' : {
                'Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```